# Push second row down for divs that are floating left

Tags: css

I have 2 rows, all divs are floating left, but I'd like the second row and all future rows to be placed after the preceeding row, not run into it. Notice in the fiddle how the second description runs into the first when the first description is long.

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wyc112y8/

css

```
 .dataleft {
 float:left;
 }
 .pushdown {
    margin-bottom:40px;
 }
 .thedatadescr {
 margin-top:8px;text-transform:Capitalize;font-size:13px;width:300px;
 }

 .thedata {
 margin-top:8px;text-transform:Capitalize;width:300px;
 }
 .thedatahalf {
 margin-top:8px;text-transform:Capitalize;width:145px;text-align:left;
 }
```

html

```
 <div id="wraprow1" class="pushdown">
 <div id="data-date" class="dataleft thedatadescr fontr" style="">long descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong descriptionlong description</div>
 <div id="data-company" class="dataleft thedatahalf fontr" style="margin-left:5px;">$12</div>
 <div id="data-company" class="dataleft thedatahalf fontr" style="margin-left:9px;">100</div>
 </div>


 <div id="wraprow2" class="pushdown">
 <div id="data-date" class=" thedatadescr fontr" style="">Second description</div>
 <div id="data-company" class="dataleft thedatahalf fontr" style="margin-left:5px;">$12</div>
 <div id="data-company" class="dataleft thedatahalf fontr" style="margin-left:9px;">100</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `#wraprow2 {
    clear:left;
}`. Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this in your css.

```
.pushdown {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```